# how to store data in Laravel session if array key exists it will append with the same key esle it will make a new array key

Tags: laravel-8

my code is given below i have request_id which i am taking as input and i am also taking a employee_id as an input i  wnat to store in Laravel session request_id and employee_id using a condition the condition is when request_id is in array employee_id will append the existance  request_id array  otherwise it will creates new array.

```
        if($request->input('request_id')){
            $req = \App\Models\Request::find($request->input('request_id')); 
            if(!empty($req)){
                $employee_id = $request->input('employee_id');
                
                $reqId = $request->input('request_id') . '_';
                $sessionData = (array)Session::put('request_employee_data', $reqId);
                if(array_key_exists($reqId, $sessionData)) {
                    array_push($sessionData[$reqId], $employee_id);
                } else {
                    $sessionData[$reqId] = [$employee_id];
                }
                Session::put('request_employee_data', $sessionData);
                dd($sessionData);
 } 
}
```

the problem is, it store first one but when the request_id same next time it will replicate first one not append with the exixting request_id